# When I update the action on my form, it doesn't post

Tags: angularjs

## This works fine

```
<head>
<script>
        function UsersCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.info = "The buttons haven't been clicked yet";
            $scope.signupfolks = function () {
            $scope.info = "You've cliked the first radio option!"
            $scope.actionyo = "/users/session";
        };
        $scope.loginfolks = function () {
            $scope.info = "You've cliked the second option!";
            $scope.actionyo = "/users/session2";
    };
    }


</script>

</head>


<body>
<div ng-controller="UsersCtrl">
<form action="/users/session" method="post">
<input type="radio" ng-model="CurrentFolks" ng-change="signupfolks()" name="NewFolks" id="optionsRadios1" value="NewFolks3">
<input type="radio" ng-model="CurrentFolks" ng-change="loginfolks()" name="NewFolks" id="optionsRadios2" value="CurrentFolks3">
<button type="submit">Sign In</button>
{{info}} <!-- verifies the angular's working for this example -->
</div>
```

## This breaks it

changing

```
<form action="/users/session" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="{{actionyo}}" method="post">
```

## But in the "view source" it says

When I don't have an option button selected, it says:

```
<form action method="post">
```

When I select an option button, the source says:

```
<form action="/users/session" method="post">
```

But when I hit the submit button... it won't go. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I guess because before you hit any option button, actionyo has no value yet?

Try to set a value first in your controller:

```
function UsersCtrl($scope) {
            $scope.actionyo = "/users/session"; //set a default. WARNING: IS THIS THE DEFAULT YOU WANT?
            $scope.info = "The button haven't been clicked yet";
            // all the rest of your code
```

Comment: The problem was a semi-colon. But you bring up an interesting point. If you want to edit this I can give you credit for the answer. ;)

Comment: $scope.info = "You've cliked the first radio option!" needs a semicolon. Who knows? Maybe someone will encounter a similar problem and this question will help.